# Program Not Finding the Header File in my C++ Workspace

Tags: c++, header, ide, codeblocks

I am very new to C++ programming and have been following the C++ Primer 5th Edition book. There is an exercise requiring an object 'Sales_item' which is provided as a header file. The link had expired, so I got the code from GitHub and saved it as a header file myself (.h). I am using the Code::Blocks IDE, and saved the Sales_item.h file in the same directory as my project file. When I reopened the project, CodeBlocks had automatically created a 'header' folder in the workspace with the Sales_item file inside. I added it to the top of my current project and compiled, just to check it worked:

`#include <Sales_item.h>`

but it throws back an error and will not compile.

The body of the program doesn't really seem important; it doesn't really do anything, is just for testing, and compiles and runs fine if I remove the header file from the workspace. I have tried re-downloading the code from GitHub on a different (hopefully better) connection at Uni and resaving the file, and moving the header file to different locations within the workspace bin and obj folders. 
The error messages might hint that I'm not using C++11? I was under the impression I was, given that this was an IDE recommended in a video from 2018 and the book suggests the code is C++11. I'm not really sure how to check.
I'm sure this is a simple issue that I just don't know how to fix. Error messages at compile include the '#include , and also point inside the Sales_item.h file itself, and include 3 errors and 3 warnings (included below).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Sales_item.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1 = 2;
    int num2 = 3;

    std::cout << num1 + num2 << std::endl;

    return 0;

}

||=== Build: Debug in C++PrimerWork (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
Documents\C++ Projects\C++Primer\C++PrimerWork\main.cpp|2|fatal error: Sales_item.h: No such file or directory|

Documents\C++ Projects\C++Primer\C++PrimerWork\Sales_item.h|56|warning: defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|

Documents\C++ Projects\C++Primer\C++PrimerWork\Sales_item.h|70|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|

Documents\C++ Projects\C++Primer\C++PrimerWork\Sales_item.h|71|warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|

Documents\C++ Projects\C++Primer\C++PrimerWork\Sales_item.h|45|error: constructor required before non-static data member for 'Sales_item::units_sold' has been parsed|

Documents\C++ Projects\C++Primer\C++PrimerWork\Sales_item.h|45|error: constructor required before non-static data member for 'Sales_item::revenue' has been parsed|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

The first error states there is no such file as Sales_item.h, although it was automatically added to the workspace and is open in its own tab. Further errors also point inside the file itself (the warnings, specifically). 
The bottom two errors are what made me think the original download was corrupted in some way. In conjunction with the warnings, I also wonder if the compiler is expecting a different version of C++ or if I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea.

Comment: `#include <Sales_item.h>` should be `#include "Sales_item.h"`. Also you should add `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` to  your compiler flags.

Comment: Thankyou for the comment! The book uses < > for some reason.
This unfortunately only fixed the first error. I will try the second part of your comment now.

Comment: < > usually means look in the system folders. " " usually means look in the project first.

Comment: @Rowan Well, depends on the toolchain you're using. I'd suspect it's MinGW gcc. You can update it to the latest version, and add the mentioned compiler flags to the project properties if the current version you have don't support these yet

Comment: Thanks again, the additional compiler flag for C++11 fixed it all. I'm quite surprised this wasn't mentioned in the book since it is for novices.

Comment: It's probably not mentioned because the default C++ Standard supported and the method by which you change the Standard you wish to compile to is an implementation detail and changes from compiler to compiler.  The book can't cover the ins and outs of dozens of different compilers and compiler versions . With a more recent GCC you wouldn't have had this problem because the default Standard  would be C++ 11 or C++14

Comment: `<>` vs. `""` in detail: For the former, GCC (and all the other compilers I am aware of) look in the paths to the standard headers and all those paths you explicitly specify via `-I` command line option. For the latter, GCC *first* looks relative to current file, *then* follows all those paths the former does, too. So alternatively, you could have specified the path to the file to be included (folder only) via the already mentioned `-I` option.

Comment: @user4581301 Okay, good to know. The compiler used in this IDE is the GNU GCC and appears up to date. 
Anyway, good point and thanks for the extra info.

Comment: open a command prompt and type `gcc -v` to get the version of the gcc install. If you aren't getting version 8 or 9, it's behind the times. If it's below 6, strongly consider updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two variants of including a file differ in where the compiler will search for the header file to be included.

Actually, the paths to be included are [implementation defined](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/cpp.include) in both variants. But the standard states, too:

> A preprocessing directive of the form `#include "q-char-sequence" new-line`
>   [...] if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
>   `#include <h-char-sequence> new-line` [...].

From this follows that you could include *any* header with `""`, but not necessarily all of them with `<>`.

Usually, the *'implementation defined'* search path comprises the paths to the standard library headers (such as `cstdint`, `vector`, ...) and those you provide explicitly to the compiler (usually via `-I` command line option – but that's compiler dependent), whereas the `""` typically adds the directory the file to be compiled resides in (i. e. a path relative to the file currently compiled).

This way, you could have include paths like:

```
#include "../include/myLibrary/SomeHeader.h"
```

which might occur if you place headers and source files into different directories.

Quite a common *convention* (i. e. not mandated by the standard) is to include standard headers and those from third party libraries you link against via `<>` and those of your own project via `""`.

Answer (score 0):

when you use < > to include a header file that means the file is in the same folder as that of the other standard library file

```
#include <Sales_item.h>  
//it will look in the same folder that contains file like studio.h,string.h
   #include "Sales_item.h"   
//it will look in folder where the main cpp is stored so try "Sales_item.h"
//or add the path of Sales_item.h in your program properties
```

- look for Sales_item.cpp there must be a one because usually header files do have a cpp file with same name where the functions are defined

Comment: Thankyou for the information, and @drescherjm for the same information. I'm sure that will save me a lot of headaches in the future!

Comment: ... and additionally those folders you specify explicitly with `-I` command line option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#incude "Sales_item.h"`

In practice, the difference is in the location where the preprocessor searches for the included file.

For `#include <filename>` the preprocessor searches in an implementation dependent manner, normally in search directories pre-designated by the compiler/IDE. This method is normally used to include standard library header files.

For `#include "filename"` the preprocessor searches first in the same directory as the file containing the directive, and then follows the search path used for the #include  form. This method is normally used to include programmer-defined header files.